# How to merge two multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge, multi-index

I have dataframe #1 looks like the following:

[image: df1]

My second dataframe looks like the following:

[image: df2]

So the first dataframe uses id and date as multiindex, while the second dataframe uses date and port as multiindex.

I managed to merge the two dataframes by firstly reset_index of both dataframes and then `pd.merge(df1,df2,how='outer',on=['date','port'])` to achieve the following structure:
[image: merged]

Lastly, I just set_index of this final structure using id and date and sort on id

My question: is there a way to merge the two dataframes WITHOUT resetting their multiindex, to achieve the structure I want with id and date still being the multiindex?

Comment: if its set on index, try `join`, `combine_first` or `update` better if you add in some data, but I think your answer lies in the marked duplicate

Comment: I tried df1.join(df2,how='outer', on=['date','port']). Now I don't have to reset index before join, neither do I have to set index after join. The only thing I have to do is sort_index on the new dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
new_df = df1.merge(
        df2, how="outer", left_index=True, right_index=True
    )
```

But this will give you two columns containing port, because `df1` has `port` as column and `df2` has it as index. To counter this you can just drop the column port using this:

```
new_df.drop(['port'], axis=1, inplace=True)
```

Comment: Thank you, what I got from your method was a three-level multiindex:date id and port. And the final structure ended up with doubling the observations of what it is supposed to be. I guess I will just either reset index before merge or use join.